# How to add event listener to a ref?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I add an event listener to the **`ref`** using ReactJS Hooks (version 16.8. +)?

Here is an example where I tried to get the scroll position of certain div with overflow-auto. **`updateScrollPosition`** never gets called.

```
function Example(props) {
    scroller = useRef();    
    useEffect(() => {
        function updateScrollPosition() {
            // update the scroll position
        }
        if (scroller && scroller.current) {
            scroller.current.addEventListener("scroll", updateScrollPosition, false);
            return function cleanup() {
                 scroller.current.removeEventListener("scroll", updateScrollPosition, false);
            };
        }
    });
    return (
        <div ref={scroller}>
            <div className="overflow-auto">
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that your your outer-div wouldn't be scrolling, instead our inner div will have scroll and hence `scroll` event isn't triggered on the outer div. Change your ref to be on the inner div and it should work

```
function Example(props) {
    const scroller = useRef();
 
    useEffect(() => {
        function updateScrollPosition() {
            // update the scroll position
        }

        if (scroller && scroller.current) {
            scroller.current.addEventListener("scroll", updateScrollPosition, false);
            return function cleanup() {
                 scroller.current.removeEventListener("scroll", updateScrollPosition, false);
            };
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={scroller} className="overflow-auto">
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You need to add [] as the second parameter to useEffect()

Comment: What if my element is rendered after some data from the API comes in? The useEffect doesn't trigger.

Comment: You should store scroller.current into a local const so that when the cleanup function runs it is guarnateed to remove the event listener from the same element.