# Add event scroll for container element

Tags: reactjs

I have this code for set scroll event to window and my container, but I think it is not good to use **document** in react component

```
   const closeMenu = () => {
        setIsActionListVisible(false);
    };

useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", closeMenu);
        const layout = document.getElementsByClassName("common-home-layout");
        if (layout) {
            layout[0].addEventListener("scroll", closeMenu);
        }
    }, []);
```

Maybe do you have any better case for that?

Comment: Why would you use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `querySelector`?

Comment: I think, shouldn't use **document** inside the component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add event listener to a ref?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855030/how-to-add-event-listener-to-a-ref)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useRef instead of document

```
const layoutRef = useRef();
if (layoutRef && layoutRef.current) {
  listRef.current.addEventListener(...)

  return () => {
    layoutRef.current.removeEventListener(...)
  }
}
```